# What does "unhorsed by fences" mean?

Tags: word-usage

And is a coordinating conjunction. We use and to connect two or more words, phrases, clauses or prefixes together:

There is a sentence in "new concept english" book4(new edition),lesson 21:

> Men accustomed to struggling for survival against the elements and Indians were bewildered by politicians, bankers and businessmen, and unhorsed by fences, laws and alien taboos.

"unhorsed by fences" was connected by "and",i think it is a noun such as businessmen or laws.

Does it mean "Enclosure in the Colonization of North America"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the stated context, "unhorsed" simply means "taken aback" or shocked or stunned or stymied or bewildered or flustered. Since the pilgrims or cowboys commonly rode horses as a norm, "unhorsed" implies the opposite of their accepted normalcy. But since the term bewildered was already applied to "politicians, bankers and businessmen" then the meaning of "unhorsed" must be more akin to stymied, flustered or even encumbered. The fine differences are difficult to plumb.

Note that the cited text *groups* "fences, laws and alien taboos" as the things which draw the response of being "unhorsed". The subject is a group of three, not just "fences" alone.

Comment: "unhorsed by fences" should be a noun phrase,it is connected with "and".

Comment: No. They were **bewildered by** A, B and C, and [they were]  **unhorsed by** D, E and F.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @Kate Bunting's (correct) comment-reply to @showkey (reflected, too, at the end of @the_fens's answer), the question's text can be seen as an excellent example of nested lists, where it's important to parse the nesting correctly otherwise you run into the confusion @showkey did (sorry showkey ). The original:

> Men…were bewildered by politicians, bankers and businessmen, and unhorsed by fences, laws and alien taboos

could also be written like this:

> Men…were:
>
> - bewildered by
>
>   1. politicians,
>   2. bankers and
>   3. businessmen,
>
> and
>
> - unhorsed by
>
>   1. fences,
>   2. laws and
>   3. alien taboos.

Now, because the outer list has only two elements, I'm not really justified in criticizing the original author for being inconsistent with their use of a serial comma on the penultimate item of a list. But I'm gonna anyway, to illustrate the point! The issue is that while they don't have a comma after either "bankers" or "laws" (which are the penultimate items in each of the inner lists), they *do* have one after "businessmen" (which, since it is the last item in the first inner list is the end of the penultimate item in the outer "list").

Had I being writing it, I might have used a semi-colon, instead of a comma as the outer list separator. Thus:

> Men…were bewildered by politicians, bankers, and businessmen; and unhorsed by fences, laws, and alien taboos.

However, as I said, I'm [chancing my arm](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/chance-your-arm) by criticizing the lack of a serial comma in a two-item list. In fact, convention says *not* to do that. But as I also said, this was a really good example and it seemed a pity to miss the chance to point out the potential problem.

Still, it would have been better, and my rambling about Oxford commas and the use of semi-colons in nested lists would have been more pertinent, had the "men" in the example had a third problem, in addition to being bewildered and being unhorsed. For example:

> Men…were bewildered by politicians, bankers, and businessmen; unhorsed by fences, laws, and alien taboos; and just generally annoyed by pirates, cads, and ell.stackexchange.com pedants.

Answer (score 2):

The word "unhorsed" literally means to be knocked off the horse one is riding. Like when knights were fighting on horseback, if one of them managed to knock the other off his horse, we would say that he was "unhorsed". Often being unhorsed would be a surprising event. Like you are riding through the woods when suddenly you come to a low branch that catches you in the chest and you are unhorsed.

Here the word is being used metaphorically to mean having one's plans disrupted in a surprising way. Just like a man riding a horse who runs into a tree is surprised at how suddenly he is knocked off the horse, so a man who thinks his business plans are proceeding nicely is surprised when those plans are ruined by a law he knew nothing about. The writer contrasts the sort of difficulties these men were used to dealing with -- weather and Indian attacks and other concrete physical things -- with more abstract issues by banking and politics.